# Qual è la differenza tra "cerchio", "cerchia" e "circolo"?

Tags: word-meaning

Conosco il significato di "cerchio" come oggetto matematico. Comunque, in un senso figurato, a volte si usano le parole "cerchia" e "circolo". Mi piacerebbe sapere quale sono le differenze di significato tra queste tre vocaboli.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"[Cerchia](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/cerchia/)" deriva da "cerchio" e significa "giro". Si usava principalmente per la cerchia delle mura attorno a una città; oggi si usa soprattutto per indicare un giro ristretto di persone.

"[Cerchio](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/cerchio/)" deriva da "cĭrcŭlus" ed è principalmente l'area interna della circonferenza, ma per estensione anche il bordo della circonferenza stessa.

"[Circolo](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/circolo/)" significa "circonferenza"; ma oggi si usa soprattutto come sinonimo di "cerchia" nel senso di gruppo ristretto di persone.

**Piccola digressione**

Il motivo per cui l'immagine della circonferenza veniva utilizzata in tanti contesti diversi è probabilmente il fascino che il mondo antico aveva per l'oggetto geometrico e le sue qualità e proprietà; si pensi ad esempio al [problema isoperimetrico di Didone](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problema_di_Didone) che riguardava la determinazione della figura geometrica piana che massimizza l'area a parità di perimetro; nella leggenda Didone intuì che si trattasse del cerchio e delimitò i confini della futura Cartagine seguendo questa intuizione. Da qui l'idea che le mura debbano essere circolari? Secondo Wikipedia, le [mura](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mura_%28fortificazione%29) delle città medievali effettivamente erano spesso circolari, apparentemente per motivi religiosi (istruiti però da Aristotele e Tolomeo); ma che dietro quest'idea religiosa si nascondesse semplicemente la magia della circonferenza e delle sue proprietà matematiche?

Comment: Forse questo fatto aveva anche un senso pratico: quello di costruire la città più grande con la stessa quantità di materiali per costruire il muro di cinta. Trovo molto curiosa l'esistenza in italiano di queste tre parole che corrispondono a un solo vocabolo in molte lingue.

Comment: @Charo Ci sono altre parole latine che hanno originato una “doppia discendenza”: *soldo* e *solido*, *aia* e *area*; vedi http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/latinismi_(Enciclopedia_dell'Italiano)/

Comment: @greg: Penso che questo fenomeno sia presente in tutte le lingue derivate dal latino, ma quello che ha attirato la mia attenzione è il fatto che questi tre vocaboli si traducano con la stessa parola in tutte le altre lingue che conosco.